# Is it possible to switch between AWS accounts without signing out first?

Tags: amazon-web-services

My organisation uses AWS Federation to handle multiple AWS accounts. However, every time I try to log into another account, I get the following error:

> You must first log out before logging into a different AWS account.

This requires me to click "Sign out", and sign into the account again. This can become very tedious when often switching between multiple accounts.

Is it possible to switch between accounts without having to sign out first?

Comment: Use Firefox with container tabs. Use one container type per account.

Comment: You could assume roles into accounts, which isn't the same thing. We use ADFS federation and I don't have to sign out to change accounts. I just go to our SSO page (which is https sso.ORGANISATIONNAME.com/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon), choose another account, and I'm signed into that account. I've done the same in other organisations. I wonder if there's something not quite right with your SSO setup.

Comment: TIL about firefox container tabs. Thanks @Sven. For others, it's an add-on, and [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/) is its page.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a `federation` link to switch accounts and roles i.e. `signin.aws.amazon.com/federation?Action=login` with a `Destination`, `Issuer` and `SigninToken` per [step 5 here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_enable-console-custom-url.html#STSConsoleLink_programPython) the solution is to build a link that both logs you out of your existing account and federates into the console.  Call the `logout` api with a `redirect_uri` set to a url encoded version of the federation link.

`https://us-east-1.signin.aws.amazon.com/oauth?Action=logout&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fus-east-1.signin.aws.amazon.com%2Ffederation%3FAction%3Dlogin%26Destination%3D...%26Issuer%3D...%26SigninToken%3D...`

Comment: This did not work for me. I was redirected to https://aws.amazon.com/console/ for some reason.

In theory, this should work

Comment: It definitely works, I do it multiple times a day.  Have you confirmed your redirect_uri works if you are signed out of the console?  Try hitting the non-url-encoded version of the redirect_uri and make sure it is working.

Comment: yes the url works when I am signed out, tried both url encoded and decoded strings, both failed

Comment: When you say both failed, 1 should work if you are signed out and have a valid federation link.  Note the SigninToken is only good for a short time period.  This takes you to aws.amazon.com right? https://signin.aws.amazon.com/oauth?Action=logout&redirect_uri=https://aws.amazon.com

Comment: I found I had some difficulty getting this to work when I didn't put us-east-1 in front of the signin urls, try taking this string and replace TOKEN at the end with the federation token, it should dump you in the s3 console:  https://us-east-1.signin.aws.amazon.com/oauth?Action=logout&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fus-east-1.signin.aws.amazon.com%2Ffederation%3FAction%3Dlogin%26Destination%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fus-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com%252Fs3%252Fhome%26SigninToken%3DTOKEN

Comment: @perpil tyvm!!! read your comment and assumed any region would work, but surprised to find that specifically it only works with `us-east-1`, which on re-read is exactly what you said ! (the URI in the Destination query param can have the proper region tho)

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out - [Granted](https://docs.commonfate.io/granted/introduction), a CLI to access the AWS console for multiple accounts and regions at once and allows multiple cloud accounts to be opened in your web browser simultaneously.

With Granted you can directly open the console from your terminal!